# Using a SQL database file as project files

Tags: sql, xml, sqlite, database-design

I am wondering if it makes sense to use multiple SQL database files like sqllite (which I believe is single file based?) as project files in my software. The project files contain basic information as well as multiple records (spectra) with lists of parameters (floating point values) and lists of measurement data (also floating point).

I currently use my own binary format, which is a pain to maintain. I tried to use XML which works very well, but the file sizes explode (500 kB before, 7.5 MB as XML).
Now I wonder if I can structure SQL databases to contain this kind of information and effectively load and save this data in my .NET software.

(I am not very experienced in SQL) so:

> > Can SQL tables contain sub-tables (like subnodes in XML) or be linked to other tables?

*E.g. Can I make a table for the record, and this table has subtables for the lists of measurement data and parameters?*

> > Will this be more efficient than XML in terms of storage space?

Comment: *Yes* to all of that, its what Databases are designed to do. One table can form a relationship with another by sharing a common key value. (https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

Comment: So I basically would make one big "measurement data" table with say an X and Y column and a foreign key column where I would enter the record-ID of the record to which the datapoint belongs?

Comment: Possibly, you would need to read up on relational database design and pick the best model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with a SQLite database. It can be easily implemented into .NET using the System.Data.SQLite Project, that can even be used with AnyCPU Builds.

It is working very nicely, both performance and storage space wise.

You still need to take a lot of care with different versions of your databases. If you try and save a new scheme into a database using an older scheme, some columns or tables might not exist. You need to implement a migration method to a new database file for this.

The real advantage is, that it is an open format, and I stand behind the premise, that the stuff a user saves is his, and does not need to be hidden in an obscure, file structure, if the latter does not bring any significant advantages to the table.
If the user can no longer use your software, he or she can still access all data, using other tools like the Database Browser for SQLite if need be.